# How can I use the Facebook Javascript API to automatically make a user like a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I was reading through the docs and I guess I can do this if the user gives me "publish_stream" permissions.

Is there a Facebook Javascript API that makes the user like a page? Just as if they had clicked on a Like button.

Comment: so far as i know like a page do not work by any api

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to like web pages, or Facebook pages through any API, except for very few approved apps.

You'll need to use a like button.